# How to change value of a key from terminal among non-unique keys in a .conf file?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, fedora, configuration

I have a .conf file in key/value format. But there may be some non-unique keys. Distinction between them is like below:

```
###
### [meta]
###
### Controls the parameters for the Raft consensus group that stores metadata
### about the InfluxDB cluster.
###

[meta]
  # Where the metadata/raft database is stored
  dir = "/var/lib/influxdb/meta"

 # Automatically create a default retention policy when creating a 
database.
  # retention-autocreate = true

  # If log messages are printed for the meta service
  # logging-enabled = true

###
### [data]
###
### Controls where the actual shard data for InfluxDB lives and how it is
### flushed from the WAL. "dir" may need to be changed to a suitable         place
### for your system, but the WAL settings are an advanced configuration. The
### defaults should work for most systems.
###

[data]
  # The directory where the TSM storage engine stores TSM files.
  dir = "/var/lib/influxdb/data"

  # The directory where the TSM storage engine stores WAL files.
  wal-dir = "/var/lib/influxdb/wal"
```

What I want to achieve is to write a script in fedora to change value of `dir` key under `data` block. I saw a similar script for unique keys in here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464760/modify-config-file-using-bash-script). But this does not work for me unfortunately. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your filename is foo.conf and you want to change dir value to "/dev/sdh",  below code will replace dir keyword only for data section.

```
sed -re '/^\[data\]$/,/^\[/ s/^(\s+)*(dir = .*)$/\1dir = "\/dev\/sdh"/' foo.conf
```

```
/^\[data\]$/,/^\[/
```

This part makes sed works for only "data" section. You can replace "data" to any keyword to make it work for any section.

Comment: Output of `sudo sed -i -e '/^\[data\]$/,/^\[/ s/^dir = .*$/dir = "/dev/sdh"/' /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf` command is `sed: -e expression #1, char 41: unknown option to s'`. This one `sudo sed -i -e '/^\[data\]$/,/^\[/ s/^dir = .*$/dir = "new_value"/' /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf` does not produces any output but also the file content does not change.

Comment: @JollyRoger You should escape /. Try this sudo sed -i -e '/^\[data\]$/,/^\[/ s/^dir.*$/dir = "\/dev\/sdh"/' /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf

Comment: Hey, I changed the content of the file to exactly how I wrote above and it worked. But actually there are some comment lines starting with a `#` or some other keys as well. These may cause to not to be changed I guess. How can I escape from them? I am updating the sample file in my answer now.

Comment: @JollyRoger It is because trailing space character. I will update my answer to work any case.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!